# PDO Prepared Statement to UPDATE substring based on position

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, substring

I'm brand new to stackoverflow and my PDO skills are limited, so I'm asking for help from someone who knows more than I do.

I use PDO prepared statements almost exclusively and for one particular app I've been fetching an entire string, modifying, then updating it.

What I would like to do is update a substring based on a positional value sent along with the modified string.

For example, if my string is "abcdefg" I would like to be able to send the string "z" along with the integer 2 which would replace "b" with "z" so the stored string would now read "azcdefg".

The following code is not correct, I know, but it shows the general outline of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$newstring = $_POST['newstring'];
$integer = $_POST['integer'];

$sql = "UPDATE table SET string=? WHERE user=?";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute( [substring $integer] $newstring, $user]);
```

Again, the code is totally not right, at least with respect to the substring line, because I have no idea how to tell it to update just a specific substring position with a new string.

Comment: _"I'm brand new to stackoverflow"_  excellent job on your first question; clear problem statement with expected results. Well done . Is there a reason you can't retrieve the string, update it in PHP and then set the new string back into the DB?

Comment: From the duplicate, I'd go with the `INSERT()` function option, eg `UPDATE table set string = INSERT(string, ?, ?, ?) WHERE user = ?` and `$stmt->execute([$integer, 1, $newstring, $user])`

Comment: @Phil Thank you for your response. I can retrieve the string, update, then set it back, but the string is 50k long and I just wanted to reduce the load.

Comment: @Phil Works perfectly just as you described. The "question has already been answered" answer really didn't help me, but your response was exactly the correct answer.